# Azure Invalid SSL Binding The following host names do not match the certificates:

Tags: azure, ssl

ANSWERED MYSELF:

This function would not work in Azure Portal, but did work in Azure management console.  I posted a note about this on MSDN.

====

I need SSL for many subdomains of mydomain.com that will point to many corresponding azurewebsites.net web sites (as App Services in one account)

I purchased a GoDaddy wildcard SSL Certificate for *.mydomain.net, then followed all the steps here, which is how to get the certificate from GoDaddy and then upload it to Azure,

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#bkmk_configuressl

and here, which has a little more detail on the upload to Azure.

http://azure.codegrains.com/2013/07/step-by-step-guide-for-implementing.html

Everything was working fine, however in the latter link, in Azure, in the Upload Certificate step, when I get to the step SSL bindings, I get this messsage:

```
Invalid SSL Binding 
The following host names do not match the certificates:   
Hostname: mydomain.net -> Certificate Hosts: *.mydomain.net;mydomain.net
```

Since the certificate is a wildcard certificate

What might be causing that and how might it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

See answer at top of post.  Net:  worked in azure management console, did not work in azure portal.

Comment: There was an issue with SAN/Multi domain certificates. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is also work for portal.azure.com. I did for my web application.

You custom domain and wildcard domain name must me same then bind you ssl with custom domain.

This will work for you.

Comment: Tnx for input. The custom domain name and wildcard domain name were the same, from the start. I fixed through the management console, when it would not take on the portal, with no other changes.   So, I'm not going to reset everything to test your suggestion. Maybe it would work in some other case.  Maybe it was the sequence of how the custom domain names were added.  In any case, I believe there is an anomaly in the operation of the portal, which I tripped over.  Hard to believe the portal would have a flaw; I ran into something similar with adding custom domains in the first place, so..

Comment: Ok, Yes there is some slightly change between old or new portal. some times its little bit confused.